# Getting hover selector to work on anchor containing other elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

Using html 5, I have an anchor element that contains block elements (e.g., p elements). I want the text within the p elements to change on hover—they don't.

```css
p {
  color: #222222;
}

a:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="test.htm">This changes color on hover</a>.</p>
<a href="test.htm">
  <p>This doesn't change color on hover.</p>
</a>
```

In my case, there are numerous elements within the anchor element and I can't change the CSS styles of those elements (e.g., I can't change the hover selector for p elements).

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add a specified id to the p element that needs to have a custom hover action.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question but cant you just have this? p:hover{
    color: red !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` won't inherit the hover color from an `a` tag around since it has its own `color` parameter (thanks to @BoltClock). But you can use `a:hover, a:hover p { ... }` as a selector to get what you want:

```css
p {
  color: #222222;
}

a:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:hover p
{
  color: red !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="test.htm">This changes color on hover</a>.</p>
<a href="test.htm">
  <p>This also changes color on hover.</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Still wrong. There is nothing in the spec that forbids a block element inheriting from an inline ancestor. The p doesn't inherit because it has a color: #222222 declaration applied to it, it's as simple as that.

Comment: @BoltClock You are right. Since I still supplied a working code solution and don't want to delete that, I changed the text of my answer according to your comment.

Comment: Perfect, Johnannes!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will change the hover selector for all the p element inside an anchor element

```css
p {
    color: #222222;
}

a:link {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: red !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a p:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="test.htm">This changes color on hover</a>.</p>
<a href="test.htm"><p>This doesn't change color on hover.</p></a>
```